# Conditional Required Field in SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, validation, list-validation

I know how I can make the conditional formatting based on one selection, but I have an issue with multiple selections.

I have a City dropdown column with three options: Test, Test1, Test3. My other column is FirstName. If users select either Test or Test 1, the FirstName column should be mandatory.

The below formula works with only one selection:

```
=IF([City]="Test",IF(ISBLANK([FirstName]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

Comment: Did you enable multiple selection on `City` column?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of SharePoint.

You cannot use multiple selection choice column in list validation or calculated column formulas.

Comment: Hi Harris, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.